# How to prevent android asynchronous service running more than once in parallel

Tags: android, asynchronous

I use an android service to update data every 5 minutes from the mobile to a server across the phone network.  The service does the following:

1. Service starts
2. Alarm is set to trigger the start of the service in another 5 minutes
3. An asynchronous data upload is initiated (which usually takes about 20 seconds)
4. selfstop is used to shutdown the service  (Note this happens almost immediately after (2) as step (3) occurs on a new thread.

My problem is this. Usually it all works fine, however for some reason the asynchronous data upload gets bogged down and takes longer than 5 minutes and so another service commences which triggers the upload again IN PARALLEL.

I'm sure this is an easy problem to fix - I just want to know a way of checking (i.e. via some sort of semiphore or something) within the service.onStartCommand(..) method whether or not the upload from a previously initiated service is still running.  If it is, I will not execute the upload.

The process needs to be fullproof because if the service sets an 'ISRUNNING' Flag and then drops out without resetting it - no more uploads will ever occur. This can't happen.  There needs to be a failsafe.

thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code which you are currently using. So we may be help you

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the time that you start the download in a variable, then do the download.

If it takes less than 5 mins then set the next time from 5 minutes from when the download started (step 3).

Then, if it takes more than 5 minutes you can decide how long it should be, perhaps have it start the download again immediately.

Or, what I would do is reverse steps 2 and 3 and set the timer for 5 minutes after the download finishes.

**UPDATE:**

`AsyncTask` should only be used for short tasks, as cYrixmorten mentioned.
http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/asynctask-android-example-part-1/

So, if it may take a long time just use two threads, one to do the download, and one to time the download and if it takes too long, kill it.

Have this be the main thread:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
                       // download code here
        }
    }

}
```

The monitoring thread:

```
class MonitorTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            final int value = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 30);
                                    downloadthread.interrupt();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bar.setProgress(value);

        }
    }

}
```

And the main function:

```
// downloadthread is defined at the class level
downloadthread = new Thread(new Task()).start(); 
new Thread(new MonitorTask ()).start();
```

I haven't tried this code, but something like it should work.

Basically, just stop the download thread if it takes too long, and then reset the timer to try again.

Comment: HI James. If I wait until the download finishes to reset the timer, then if for some reason the download fails, the next timer will never get set

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use IntentService instead.

From the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

Thus the uploads can never run in parallel.

Using IntentService should be done for the asynchronous data upload, just to clarify.

Comment: I was led to believe that intent services are no ideal for long operations?  I'll investigate though, thanks

Comment: In my opinion it is rather AsyncTask's which should not take more than 10 - 20 secs max. Do not think the same applies to IntentService. Happe coding